# Navigate from one sidebar menu items to another in shiny Dashboard in R

Tags: r, shiny, dashboard

I tried this code, to move from one sidebar menu items to another.But it's not working.For example: I want Introduction tab to have description text only, data tab to have datatableoutput and visualisation tab to have tabset panel. I can't find out where I am doing the mistake.
**HERE is my code:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)           
  sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(width = 350, 
    sidebarMenu(id ="tabs",

      menuItem("Introduction", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
      br(),
      menuItem("Data", tabName = "data", icon = icon("th")),
      br(),
      menuItem("Visualization", tabName = "Visual", icon = icon("th")
      ),

      br(),
      fileInput("file" , "Dataset"),
      textInput("hashtag", "Enter Hashtag",""),
      sliderInput("datasize","# of tweets",min = 100,max = 10000,""),
      submitButton("Submit","", width = 80),

      tags$style(type='text/css', "button#Submit { margin-right: 50px; }"),
      tags$style(type = "text/css",
                 ".submit label {  font-size: 50px;}"

      ),
      br(),
      br(),
      radioButtons("paramerters","Select the parameters",list("Sentiment","Emotion","Time series
                                                              ","Location","Wordcloud","Age","Gender"),""),
      tags$style(type = "text/css",
                 ".radio label {  font-size: 16px;}"

      ),
      br(),
      actionButton("action",label = "Analyse!",class = "butt1", icon = icon("refresh"), style = "font-size: 130%; color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"),
      tags$style(type='text/css', "button#action { margin-left: 50px; }")
    )
  )

  body <- dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
              br(),
              br(),
              h2("Introduction",  align = "center", style = "font-family: 'times'; color:red"),
              br(),
              p("On 8 November 2016, Prime Minister of India Narendra Modi announced the",a("demonetisation", href = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Indian_banknote_demonetisation"),"of all Rs 500  and Rs 1,000 banknotes of the Mahatma Gandhi Series by the Government of India. 
                In the announcement, Modi declared that use of all 500 rs and 1000rs banknotes of the Mahatma Gandhi Series would be invalid past midnight, and announced the issuance of new 500rs and 2000rs banknotes
                of the Mahatma Gandhi New Series in exchange for the old banknotes.
                The government claimed that the action would curtail the shadow economy and crack down on the use of illicit and counterfeit cash to fund illegal activity and terrorism."
                ,width= 12, align ="bottom", style = "font-family: 'times', font-size: 45px"),
                    br(),
                  br(),
                br(),
              br(),
            br(),
          br(),
        br(),
        br(),
        br(),
        br(),
        br(),
        br(),
        br(),
        br(),
        br(),
        br(),
        br(),
        br(),
        br(),
              column(align="left",
                  h2("About this app ...", align = "left", style = "font-family: 'times'; color:red; font-size: 130%"),
                  p("This app helps you to explore and visualize the Demonetisation in india 2016."
                    ,style = "font-family: 'times', font-size: 10pt"),
                  width = 4,
                  align = "bottom"))

  ),

  tabItem(tabName = "Data",
          box(title = "DEmonetisation related Tweets 2016",
              width = 12, 
              DT::dataTableOutput('da.tab'))

          ),

    tabItem(tabName = "visual",
            mainPanel(
              tabsetPanel(
              tabPanel("Tab1", "First tab content"),
              tabPanel("Tab2", "Tab content 2")
              )
            )
    )

  )


ui <-  dashboardPage(skin = "yellow",
              dashboardHeader(title= HTML(paste(icon('inr'),"DEMONETisation")),titleWidth = 350 ),
              sidebar,
              body)
```

Please help me with code.
Thanks.